# How do I copy music files in order?

Tags: command-line

Is there a command to copy music files in order?

I need to copy MP3s which are in folders by "**Artist - Album**" to a USB stick.

The MP3s must be copied in order, for example `01 Can You Feel It.mp3` should be copied before `02 Skyway.mp3`.

Comment: Just wondering. What is your actual use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy files in order with commandline or nautilus. But you can use midnight commander to copy some files in order. Install it on terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Comment: thanks for the response. unfortunately i still can't figure how to copy in order. i've looked through some man pages and whatnot - am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any ready-to-use software to do this, you can very easily write one.

In python, a script to recursively copy all files with there respective folders to a new folder in order, could look like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import shutil

try:
    from_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(sys.argv[1]))
    to_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(sys.argv[2]))
except:
    print "Usage: copyinorder <from path> <to path>"
    exit()

if not os.path.exists(to_path) or not os.path.exists(from_path):
    exit("Error: both paths must exist.")

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(from_path):
    if file_names:
        new_dir_path = os.path.join(to_path, os.path.relpath(dir_path, from_path))
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir_path):
            os.makedirs(new_dir_path)
        for name in sorted(file_names):
            dest = os.path.join(new_dir_path, name)
            src = os.path.join(dir_path, name)
            shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
            print "copied {0} \n to {1}".format(src, dest)
```

You could just save it somewhere (e.g. as "copyinoder"), make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x copyinorder`) and run it like this:

```
copyinorder ~/Music/DavidBowie /media/N900/Music/
```

Note that in this case the "DavidBowie" folder will not be recreated.

Note also, that if the files are not as nicely named as in your example, then `sorted` might not be the order you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code should do what you're looking for.  Modify the `sort` portion to alter the sorting behaviour to taste.

`for i in "$(ls *.mp3 | sort)"; do cp "$i" "/destination/$i"; done`

ETA: This might only work on a single directory at a time, but you can try `ls -R`, though I don't know if that would copy recursively.